# How to reverse a netsh firewall command in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, firewall, gaming

I wanted to appear as offline in Valorant and tried to type in `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="lolchat" dir=in remoteport=5223 protocol=TCP action=block` in my command prompt.

Now it takes way more time to start the game and where my friendlist usually is, there is now just "service unavailable". I want to reset this and make it back to normal settings. I already tried to redownload the game but that didnt work. Please help me, I would appreciate that a lot!

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question. If you want to delete it, use the _Delete_ button or _Flag_ it for moderator's attention with appropriate message.

Comment: Just run `netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="lolchat"` and that will delete it via command line.

Comment: @DrinkSomePimpJuiceIT That's basically an answer. You could post it as such.

Comment: Good idea, I just added it to the already posted answer since it's essentially the same thing just one way versus the other.

Answer (score 2):

From admin elevated command prompt to delete the firewall rule run:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="lolchat"
```

Or go to Windows Firewall from the Control Panel and then delete the rule named **lolchat**, as picture below to delete it via the GUI method:

[image]